# Access EJB in JSP gives null pointer

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to get a User entity from my database in a JSP where I iterate through Messages entity.

Each Message contains its author's ID.

Here's my servlet's code

```
public class messageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private MessageDAO messageDAO;
    @EJB
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Long clean_id = Long.valueOf(req.getParameter("id"));
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity) req.getSession().getAttribute("me");

        if (user == null) {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } else {
            if (clean_id != null) {
                List<MessageEntity> messages = messageDAO.findByTopic(clean_id);
                if (messages != null) {
                    req.setAttribute("messages", messages);
                    req.setAttribute("userDAO", new JpaUserDAO());
                    req.getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(req, response);
                }
            } else {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(req, response);
            }
        }

    }
```

And my message.jsp

```
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="com.forum.entity.UserEntity"%>
<%@page import="com.forum.dao.jpa.JpaUserDAO"%>
<%@page import="com.forum.entity.MessageEntity"%>
<%@page import="com.forum.dao.UserDAO"%>
<%@page import="javax.ejb.EJB"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Category page</title>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ include file="navbar.jsp" %>

        <h1>Messages</h1>
        <ul>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty user}">

                    <li>

                        <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="message">
                            <c:out value="${message.getMessage_author_id()}"></c:out>
                            <c:set var="user" value="${userDAO.find(message.getMessage_author_id())}"></c:set>

                              <c:out value="${user.getUser_email()}"></c:out>
                            <c:out value="${message.getMessage_author_id()}"/><br />
                            <c:out value="${message.getMessage_created()}"/><br />
                            <c:out value="${message.getMessage_content()}"/><br />
                            <c:if test="${user_role == 'mod' || user_role == 'admin'}">
                                <a href="editmessage?id=${message.getMessage_id()}">Edit</a>
                                <a href="deletemessage?id=${message.getMessage_id()}">Delete</a>
                            </c:if>
                            <br /><br />
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:url value="/doLogin" var="loginUrl" />
                        <a href="${loginUrl}">${message.getMessage_content()}</a>
                    </c:otherwise>

                </c:choose>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JpaUsersDAO called in the servlet:

```
package com.forum.dao.jpa;

import com.forum.dao.UserDAO;
import com.forum.entity.UserEntity;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
@Stateless
public class JpaUserDAO implements UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;



    @Override
    public UserEntity find(Long id) {
        return em.find(UserEntity.class, id);
    }
}
```

When I iterate in the JSP, for each messages, I'd like to get the User corresponding to the message's author ID using the JpaUserDAO.find() to be able to display the author's informations.
When I try to do that I get a NULL pointer exception in the find() function and can't really figure how to solve my problem.

Is there a solution to do what I want easily?

Comment: The `EntityManager` is not being injected because it's not being created. Looks like your persistence.xml file has a problem.

Comment: It works everywhere else tho, I only use Entitymanagers injections in all my classes and it works everywhere except there.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new instance of `JpaUserDAO`?
This looks like the cause of your problem.
The following line in `messageServlet` doesn't make sense;

```
req.setAttribute("userDAO", new JpaUserDAO());
```

You have declared `JpaUserDAO` as a EJB.

```
@Stateless
public class JpaUserDAO implements UserDAO {
```

So when you use `@Inject` or `@EJB` the instance will be created for you and injected into the appropriate place.

Why not handle the line `userDAO.find(message.getMessage_author_id())` in the Servlet separately?